# Caffe2: Load ONNX model, and inference single threaded on multi-core host / docker

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, caffe2, onnx

I'm having trouble running inference on a model in docker when the host has several cores. The model is exported via PyTorch 1.0 ONNX exporter:

```
torch.onnx.export(pytorch_net, dummyseq, ONNX_MODEL_PATH)
```

Starting the model server (wrapped in Flask) with a single core yields acceptable performance (cpuset pins the process to specific cpus) `docker run --rm -p 8081:8080 --cpus 0.5 --cpuset-cpus 0 my_container`

response from `ab -c 1 -n 1000 http://0.0.0.0:8081/predict\?itemids\=5,100`

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      5
  75%      5
  80%      5
  90%      7
  95%     46
  98%     48
  99%     49
```

But pinning it to four cores gives completely different stats for the same ab-call `docker run --rm -p 8081:8080 --cpus 0.5 --cpuset-cpus 0,1,2,3 my_container`

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      9
  66%     12
  75%     14
  80%     18
  90%     62
  95%     66
  98%     69
  99%     69
 100%     77 (longest request)
```

Model inference is done like this, and except this issue it seems to work as expected. (This runs in a completely separate environment from the model export of course)

```
from caffe2.python import workspace
from caffe2.python.onnx.backend import Caffe2Backend as c2
from onnx import ModelProto


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.predictor = create_caffe2_predictor(path)

    @staticmethod
    def create_caffe2_predictor(onnx_file_path):
        with open(onnx_file_path, 'rb') as onnx_model:
            onnx_model_proto = ModelProto()
            onnx_model_proto.ParseFromString(onnx_model.read())
            init_net, predict_net = c2.onnx_graph_to_caffe2_net(onnx_model_proto)
            predictor = workspace.Predictor(init_net, predict_net)
        return predictor


    def predict(self, numpy_array):
        return self.predictor.run({'0': numpy_array})

** wrapper flask app which calls Model.predict() on calls to /predict **
```

`OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` is also present in the container environment, which had *some* effect, but it is not the end issue.

The benchmark stats you're seeing here are run on a local machine with 8 hyperthreads, so I shouldn't be saturating my machine and affect the test. These results also show up in my kubernetes environment, and I'm getting a large amount of CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) throttling there.

I'm running in a kubernetes environment, so there's no way for me to control how many CPUs the host exposes, and doing some sort of pinning there seems a bit hacky as well.

Is there any way to pin caffe2 model inference to a single processor? Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Is the caffe2.Predictor object not suited to this task?

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I've added the simplest possible reproducable example I can think of here, with a docker-container and run-script included: https://github.com/NegatioN/Caffe2Struggles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but if your goal is to serve PyTorch models (and only PyTorch models, as mine is now) in production, simply using [PyTorch Tracing](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) seems to be the better choice.

You can then load it directly into a C++ frontend similarly to what you would do through Caffe2, but PyTorch tracing seems more well maintained. From what I can see there are no speed slowdowns, but it is a whole lot easier to configure.

An example of this to get good performance on a single-core container is to run with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` as before, and export the model as follows:

```
from torch import jit
### Create a model
model.eval()
traced = jit.trace(model, torch.from_numpy(an_array_with_input_size))
traced.save("traced.pt")
```

And then simply run the model in production in pure C++ following the above guide, or through the Python interface as such:

```
from torch import jit
model = jit.load("traced.pt")
output = model(some_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

`workspace.GlobalInit(["caffe2", "--caffe2_omp_num_threads=1"])`

Comment: Hi Sergey. Sadly that didn't change anything. I'm pretty sure having `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` exported to environment gives the exact same result.
Are there any other likely sinners to evaluate? Or any easy way to find the docs for those command line parameters / globalInit parameters that we can set on caffe2? Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Do you see something about setting omp_num_threads in the logs?
Here is the logic for related flags and environments variables, with logging: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/caffe2/core/init_omp.cc

Comment: Yes, the logs at least state that both MKL and OMP have one thread. `[V init_omp.cc:69] Caffe2 running with 1 MKL threads` `[V init_omp.cc:42] Caffe2 running with 1 OMP threads`

Comment: I've added a repo with a docker container to hopefully reproduce the results if you would be willing to look at it: https://github.com/NegatioN/Caffe2Struggles

Comment: I think this might be because caffe2 is explicitly setting the threadpool size to be as large as the number of logical cpus https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18013 . In that case, it seems like there's no other option than having someone patch it with a fix.